# adding boost by field to a prefix and match_phrase_prefix queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add score boost to different fields in my es query so that a certain field will have precedence over another.

My query looks like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "prefix": {
               "title": "נפצ"
            }},{
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
               "sub_title": "נפצע קש"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

For some reason, with the prefix and match_phrase_prefix it seems like i cant add score boosters.

What i would like to achieve should look something like this:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "prefix": {
               "title": "נפצ"
               "score": 2
            }
                   },{
            "prefix": {
               "sub_title": "נפ"
               "score": 1
            }
                  }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[edited] Using `boost` should solve the issue. According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html), something like that must work for you (although I haven't tried it on my own):

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "prefix": {
               "title": {
                  "value": "נפצ",
                  "boost": 2.0
               }
            }},{
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
               "sub_title": {
                  "query": "נפצע קש",
                  "boost": 1.0
               }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried your suggestion in Sense add on to chrome, and the query doesnt work this way.

Comment: I have modified the query and edited the answer: In match_phrase_prefix, I replaced 'value' with 'query' and works for me. Does it work for you too?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and quick edit - i will only be able to tell you if it works on sunday :)

Comment: It works now! thank you very much for all your help. my only comments to your solution are these: i didnt use a float for the boost values i used an int. and also i didnt use query which didnt work for me but i used value.

Comment: Not relevant anymore:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html